# Use state is not re rendering after i changed state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3BhF.png)

Here i created a form  and from there i am trying to update the dummyData when i console.log the data it's shows the updated one and if change anything in my code which triggers components to re-render it displays the new data,but not on submission of noteForm it does not re render the noteBlock.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code as part of the post.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately, also update state in **immutable** way

Answer (score -1):

To update the state, you need to follow an immutable approach using callbacks.
See React documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Example from the documentation

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```